# Combining Regular, Bold, and Italic Fonts in FontForge

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I have a Regular font that does not support bold+italics. I also have the separate Bold+Italics fonts from that same family. Is it possible to use FontForge to combine all three into one font file that supports the standard font plus bold+italics, without having to manually re-create the bold+italic forms in the regular font file?

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: What format font files do you have? (Are you trying to create a .TTC "collection" file?) Usually it's completely normal for the different styles to be in separate files; the OS knows they're from the same family.